# Flutter - ListView.builder not scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my `ListView.builder` inside `Expanded` widget which render widgets correctly on the screen but I cannot scroll the widgets rendered by it.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getPostsForUid(),
        builder: (_, snap) {
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snap.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                if (snap.data[index]['post_type'] == 'real_estate') {
                  return realEstate(snap, index);
                }
                else if (snap.data[index]['post_type'] == 'video_sharing') {
                  return videoSharing(snap, index);
                }
                else {
                  return Text('');
                }
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using ScrollPhysics() class,
`physics: ScrollPhysics()`,
here is the [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html) for reference for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your physics to `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`.
The docs state the following:

> Scroll physics that always lets the user scroll.
> This overrides the default behavior which is to disable scrolling when there is no content to scroll. It does not override the handling of overscrolling.
> On Android, overscrolls will be clamped by default and result in an overscroll glow. On iOS, overscrolls will load a spring that will return the scroll view to its normal range when released.

Here is an image of "overscroll glow" for you to understand what that means.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mMn4.png]

Consider using `shrinkWrap: false` to expand your contents in case they are bounded.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getPostsForUid(),
        builder: (_, snap) {
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snap.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                if (snap.data[index]['post_type'] == 'real_estate') {
                  return realEstate(snap, index);
                }
                else if (snap.data[index]['post_type'] == 'video_sharing') {
                  return videoSharing(snap, index);
                }
                else {
                  return Text('No data available.');
                }
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

See the docs:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html

Comment: adding AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() and shrinkWrap to false renders no widgets at all

Comment: @zrhl Please make sure that is not due to your `else` case which renders an empty text. I modified the code in my answer to accommodate for that.

Comment: @zrhl Did you test if your code produced the else case?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Physics:AlwaysScrollable()` in your `Listview`.

Comment: Added still not scrollable.

Comment: @zrhl is your listview height larger than the viewport height? You might want to `shrinkWrap: false` in case your contents are bounded. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html